# Programmatically read target platform during run time

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I want to know (for logging purposes) if the store application has been compiled for x86 / x64 / AnyCPU / Win32.

I couldn't find anything, but it seems that this information should be available during run time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to your project properties and for each platform add a **Conditional compilation symbol** (in **Build** tab). Let's say `PLATFORM_X86`, `PLATFORM_X64` and `PLATFORM_ANYCPU` (you can also use `/D` option from command line).

You can use such symbols in your code:

```
#if PLATFORM_X86
    // Code specific for X86 builds
#endif
```

If you need to do it for logging you may simply declare a constant like:

```
#if PLATFORM_X86
private const string Platform = "X86";
#elif PLATFORM_X64
private const string Platform = "X64";
#elif PLATFORM_ANYCPU
private const string Platform = "AnyCPU";
#endif
```

Of course when compiling for `AnyCPU` you can use `Environment.Is64BitProcess` to know where you're running on.

Answer (score 4):

try in this way using [`IntPtr.Size`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.intptr.size(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var result="";
if (IntPtr.Size == 8)
      result= "x64";
else
      result="x86";
```

the next method **doesn't work in windows-store-apps** as @Adriano Repetti flagged to me.
 I don't delete it only for community reason.

another way is use [`\[Module.GetPEKind Method\]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.module.getpekind.aspx)

```
 Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
 PortableExecutableKinds p;
 ImageFileMachine machineInfo;
 assembly .ManifestModule.GetPEKind(out p, out machineInfo);
```

after this line of code `machineInfo` variable should be one of:

1. `AMD64` for Targets a 64-bit AMD processor
2. `ARM` for an ARM processor
3. `I386` for 32-bit Intel processor
4. `IA64` for 64-bit Intel processor

Comment: GetPEKind is right way to do it for "normal" NET apps but GetPEKind method isn't supported in Windows Store Apps (as OP tagged his question). To check Int32 size won't tell you if you **compiled** for X86 or AnyCPU, it's just a more _dirty_ way to get same information you have in Environment.Is64Process.